# Ordenar consulta de forma intercalada

Tags: php, mysql, select

Estou tentando listar uma determinada categoria de produto. exemplo.

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM msg where tema = :tema;");
$s = 'mensagens-de-aniversario';
$consulta->bindParam(":tema", $s, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->execute();
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

if($linha['voz'] == 'vozfeminina'){
 echo "<p>".$linha['voz']." A</p>";
}

if($linha['voz'] == 'vozmasculina'){
 echo "<p>".$linha['voz']." B</p>";
}

}
```

Esta listando assim:

```
vozfeminina A, vozfeminina A, vozmasculina B, vozmasculina B
```

Teria uma forma de quando fazer essa consulta listar todos os produtos na ordem:

```
"vozfeminina A"  |  "vozmasculina B"  |  "vozfeminina A"   |  "vozmasculina B"...
```

Estou usando conexão PDO do mysql.

Comment: Mas que ordem seria essa? Não sei se foi o exemplo, mas parece que está querendo intercalar?

Comment: Isso mesmo intercalar resultado. Seria assim: tenho 4 produtos X e 4 produto Y ao listar gostaria que ficasse assim produto X, Y, X, Y, X, Y, X, Y

Comment: Mas só há um par (feminina A, masculina A; feminina B, masculina B, feminina C, masculina C) o que resultaria em `fem-A, masc-A, fem-B, masc-B`. Seria isso?

Comment: estamos quase lá. para se bem preciso seria assim. na mesma tabela tem produto feminino e produto masculino, a ideia erá listar assim produto-a, produto,b produto,a produto,b. o código acima esta listando produto a, produto a, produto b, produto b,

Comment: estou fazendo uns testes com GROUP by mais mostra só dois resultados. e já com union mostra o mesmo resultado acima.

Comment: Isso me parece [Pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possivel ordernar utilizando uma sub-consulta e variáveis:

```
SELECT voz, produto, outra_coluna
FROM (
    SELECT voz, produto, outra_coluna
    , IFNULL(@orderA, @orderA := 0)
    , IFNULL(@orderB, @orderB := 0)
    , IF(voz = 'vozfeminina', @orderA := @orderA + 1, IF(voz = 'vozmasculina', @orderB := @orderB + 1, null)) AS idx
    FROM msg
    WHERE tema = :tema
) AS a
ORDER BY idx, voz;
```

Exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/663f3/4

Comment: Ola Sanção obrigado por responder. tentei desta forma e esta listando todas as fem e todas as masc sem intercalar o resultado. mesmo assim obrigado pela força...

Comment: @wildson adicionei um fiddle funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que seja necessário algum ajuste, mas com essa logica você consegue resolver o problema. Não é uma ordenação com o mysql mas vai funcionar. Assim você faz duas consultas, uma para masc e outra para femi, e intercala na hora de exibir.

```
$s = 'mensagens-de-aniversario';
// CONSULTA DE VOZ FEMININA
$consultaF = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM msg where tema = :tema AND voz = 'vozfeminina';");
$consultaF->bindParam(":tema", $s, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consultaF->execute();
// CONSULTA DE VOZ MASCULINA
$consultaM = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM msg where tema = :tema AND voz = 'vozmasculina';");
$consultaM->bindParam(":tema", $s, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consultaM->execute();
// FAZ O FETCH DAS DUAS CONSULTAS
while ($linhaF = $consultaF->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) | $linhaM = $consultaM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    if(count($linhaF)){
     echo "<p>".$$linhaF['voz']." A</p>";
    }

    if(count($linhaM)){
     echo "<p>".$linhaM['voz']." B</p>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Opa Euler01 tudo bem.obrigado por responder. estou utilizando seu código para teste. no momento é isto que quero. mais a parte da $linhaM não esta aparecendo os dados da tabela. irei fazer alguns ajuste para ver o que esta acontecendo. valeu broder..

Comment: Voce esta usando o while do jeito que eu  coloquei? Com um operador | só?
Assim: while ($linhaF = $consultaF->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) | $linhaM = $consultaM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

Comment: se você usar um | ele executa o primeiro e o segundo. Se usar dois || ele executa o primeiro e pula.

Comment: valeu broder consegui aqui.